# Space complexity for recursive Fibonacci with memoization?

Tags: java, fibonacci, space-complexity

I have these two methods to find Fibonacci series for given number 'n'. One uses the memoization.

I would like to know how the Space complexity for these two methods differs:

```
    public static int fib(int n, int[] mem){

    if(n ==0 || n ==1 ){
        return n;
    }

    if(mem[n] > 0 ) {
        return mem[n]);
    }

    mem[n] = fib(n-1,mem) + fib(n-2,mem);

    return mem[n]; 

}
```

without memoization:

```
public static int fib(int n){

    if(n ==0 || n ==1 ){
        return n;
    }

   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct memory usage is pretty self evident - using memoization each value in fib will be calculated only once, so your space complexity will be o(n), where n is the input number to fib (the memoization array will hold n numbers).

Without memoization - no additional memory is required (the downside being many redundant calculations).

> Is the memoization array, which is passed on to each of the recursive
>   calls the same array ..or a copy of that array? In case the copy of the array
>   is passed... the space complexity would be > O(n).

You are passing the same array reference to your recursive calls.

This means your space complexity is o(n). If you were to create a new array and pass it, your memoization would fail to work, since you would have to consolidate the results of the updated new array with the previous one/s.